# how can I view the history on remote hosts with helm-eshell-history?

Tags: eshell

I'd really like to use `eshell` on remote hosts, however I have to use !N in order to call history items. I haven't found any other way to select history items and this is really inconvenient compared to `helm-eshell-history`. How can I make eshell recognize remote history ?